# How to completely reload a TFDManager in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, firedac, c++builder-10.3-rio

In my C++Builder application, i'm trying to do a configuration form where the user could change the database that FireDAC uses on runtime, to do that, i'm editing the FDConnectionDefs.ini file and saving it. So far it works using RefreshConnectionDefFile, but if i used the database once in my runtime, it won't reload and i have to close the program for the changes to actually being applied to my DB usage. How can i completly reload my TFDManager ?

Comment: I have an application where I configure the global instance of TFDManager (which is called FDManage) from settings read in by an ini file. I set FDManager->Active = false; and then set up all the connection parameters etc and then set FDManager->Active = true; Are you doing this?

Comment: Ooops: type in first line: should be: global instance of TFDManager (which is called FDManager)  -- fixed the missing "r".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RogerCigol ! I does work, also i found another workaround that is using FDManager->Close() then changing settings (RefreshConnectionDefFile for me) and thenFDManager->Open() but to be sure i used your solution since it works.